# ERROR RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

**Hola a todos, estaba siguiendo un tutorial para hacer una aplicación móvil con kotlin utilizando RecyclerView, aclarando que recién soy nuevo, pero me tope con este error.
de RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout, Como lo soluciono?** estoy investigando, pero no encontré solucion,

Mi MainActivity, creo que aqui esta el problema, intente solucionarlo, pero no pude

```
package com.example.movieapps

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.movieapps.adapter.MovieAdapter
import com.example.movieapps.model.Movie
import com.example.movieapps.restapi.RestApiAdapter
import com.example.movieapps.restapi.model.MoviesResponse
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Response

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val TAG = "MainActivity"
    var movies = mutableListOf<Movie>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        _showMovies()
    }

    private fun _showMovies(){
        var restApiAdapter = RestApiAdapter()
        var gson = restApiAdapter.gsonDeserizerMovies()
        val endPointApi = restApiAdapter.conection(gson)
        val call = endPointApi.show("now_playing","7ae1412d735f655sdgsdgsdgsd18bb2ba5c", "es-ES", 1)
        //val call = endPointApi.show()

        call.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<MoviesResponse>{
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<MoviesResponse>,
                response: Response<MoviesResponse>
            ) {
              var data = response.body()
                //Log.i("bjar",data.toString())
                with(data?.movies){
                    if(this != null){
                        movies = this
//                        for (movie in this){
//                            Log.i("bjar",movie.title + "bengy")
//                        }

                        moviesRV.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL ,false)
                        moviesRV.adapter = MovieAdapter(this)
                    }
                }
                moviesRV.adapter = MovieAdapter(this)
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<MoviesResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e(TAG, t.toString())
            }

        })


    }

}
```

Mi movie MoviesResponse

```
 package com.example.movieapps.restapi.model

import com.example.movieapps.model.Movie

class MoviesResponse {
    var movies= ArrayList<Movie>()
}
```

**Mi RestApiAdapter**

```
package com.example.movieapps.restapi

import com.example.movieapps.restapi.ResoucesURL.URL_BASE
import com.example.movieapps.restapi.deserilizer.MoviesDeserilizer
import com.example.movieapps.restapi.model.MoviesResponse
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

class RestApiAdapter {
    fun conection(gson: Gson) :EndPointApi{
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(URL_BASE)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
        return retrofit.create(EndPointApi::class.java)
    }

    fun gsonDeserizerMovies() : Gson{
        val gsonBuilder = GsonBuilder().setLenient()
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(MoviesResponse::class.java,MoviesDeserilizer())
        return  gsonBuilder.create()
    }
}

mi adapter_movie

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/linternaverde"
            android:contentDescription="TODO" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/movieTV"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#80000000"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Linterna Verde" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

este es mi activity_main

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/moviesRV"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

nose en donde estoy fallando, e seguido tal cual el tutorial. cabe mencionar que ya tengo las librerías solicitadas

Comment: ¿Estás obteniendo datos en la response de retrofit?

Comment: Estás seteando el adapter si movies no es null y después lo seteas con un Adapter pasándole por parámetro un valor que puede ser null... de todas formas es probable que el error sea porque cuando el valor es null, no estás seteando el layoutManager.  Borra el set del layoutManager aquí y ponlo en tu xml:         app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"

Answer (score 0):

**Mensaje "No adapter attached; skipping layout" en Android Studio**

El mensaje de error "No adapter attached; skipping layout" generalmente indica que no se ha adjuntado un adaptador a un componente de vista de lista, como RecyclerView o ListView. Un adaptador es necesario para proporcionar los datos y controlar la visualización de los elementos en la lista.

Toma en cuenta las siguientes consideraciones:

1. Asegúrate de tener un RecyclerView o ListView en tu diseño XML: Verifica que hayas agregado un componente RecyclerView o ListView en tu archivo de diseño XML. Por ejemplo, en el archivo "activity_main.xml", puedes agregar un RecyclerView utilizando la etiqueta <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>.
2. Crea un adaptador: Asegúrate de haber creado y configurado un adaptador para tu RecyclerView o ListView. El adaptador debe extender la clase RecyclerView.Adapter (para RecyclerView) o BaseAdapter (para ListView) y proporcionar la lógica para vincular los datos a las vistas individuales en la lista.
3. Adjunta el adaptador al RecyclerView o ListView: En tu actividad o fragmento, después de inicializar el RecyclerView o ListView, asegúrate de adjuntar el adaptador a ellos utilizando el método setAdapter() correspondiente. Por ejemplo, para un RecyclerView, puedes llamar a recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter).
4. Verifica que el adaptador tenga datos: Asegúrate de que tu adaptador tenga datos para mostrar en la lista. Puedes verificar si tu lista de datos está vacía o nula antes de adjuntar el adaptador.
5. Verifica la inicialización y el uso correcto del RecyclerView o ListView: Asegúrate de que hayas inicializado correctamente el RecyclerView o ListView en tu actividad o fragmento. Verifica que estés utilizando el identificador correcto para encontrar el componente de vista en tu código.

Con los pasos anteriores, deberías poder resolver el error "No adapter attached; skipping layout" en Android Studio y asegurarte de que tu RecyclerView o ListView esté correctamente vinculado con un adaptador para mostrar los datos en la lista.

Comment: De acuerdo a lo que escribes, **¿cómo se soluciona el problema que expone el OP?** , revisar [answer]